# Plot issues in Python

Tags: python, plot, graph

Hello I would like to modify this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

t0=29.364 # moyenne temp exe
tm=28.6 #amplitude variation ext
x= 4*10e-2
T=24*3600
w=(2*pi)/T
D=4*10e-7
delta=sqrt(2*D/w)
total_time=48*3600
t=np.arange(0, total_time, 10*60) 
temp = t0 + tm*np.exp(-x/delta)*np.cos(w*t-(x/delta)+(3*pi/2)) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(t, temp, label='temperature fluctuation')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('temperature (c)')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(18, 40, 0.5))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The functions should return 3 graphs at once, the first is the original, the second is the original but `t0 = t0 + 0.5` and `tm = tm + 0.5`, and the third `t0 = t0 - 0.5` and `tm = tm - 0.5`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure about what you mean but if you want to add ( or subtract) 0.5 from all the values of time and temperature, you can simply do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(t, temp, label='temperature fluctuation')
plt.plot(t+0.5, temp+0.5) #line to which you subtract 0.5
plt.plot(t-0.5, temp-0.5) # line to which you add 0.5
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('temperature (c)')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(18, 40, 0.5))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[The graph returned is the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2sIF.png)

Was this what you had to do?